# Count blank cells in a row except the ones on both sides

Tags: excel

My data looks like below. I want to count consecutive blank cells in a row except the blank cells at the beginning and at the end. My logic is to return the max. For the case below, the returned value should be 2, not 5.

[image]

Comment: Do you know any VBA? This would be tricky to setup using just formulae

Answer (score 0):

For **row #3**:

Say we are interested in consecutive blanks from **C3** to **J3**:

[image]

We can mark consecutive blanks with a "helper" row,  In **D4** enter:

```
=IF(AND(D3="",OR(C3="",E3="")),"X","")
```

and copy this over to cell **I4**.

Then in another cell enter:

```
=COUNTIF(C4:J4,"=X")
```

[image]

We can avoid the "helper" row if you use a VBA user defined function:

```
Option Explicit
Public Function consecb(rng As Range) As Long
    Dim nFirst As Long, nLast As Long, i As Long
    Dim roww As Long

    nFirst = rng.Find(what:="*", after:=rng(1)).Column
    nLast = rng.Find(what:="*", after:=rng(1), searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    roww = rng.Row

    For i = nFirst + 1 To nLast - 1
        If Cells(roww, i) = "" And (Cells(roww, i - 1) = "" Or Cells(roww, i + 1) = "") Then
            consecb = consecb + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

In the worksheet you would use it like:

```
=consecb(3:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a formula, using the following criteria:

- IsBlank(cell) : the cell itself should be blank.
- IsBlank(cell.Offset(0,-1)) : the cell to the left should be blank (in order not to count the beginning of the series)
- IsBlank(cell.Offset(0,1)) : the cell to the right should be blank (in order not to count the ending of the series)
- cell.Col <> 1 : in order not to count the beginning of the worksheet
- IsBlank(cell.Offset(-1,1)) : in order not to count the most right blank cell